# GitHub pages only showing ReadMe

Tags: html, git, github, hosting, github-pages

How can I resolve the issue of my website hosted on GitHub Pages only showing the README page? I'm unable to select any sources under the "source" tab in the Pages settings. Any suggestions on how to fix this?(Link to Github:https://github.com/MaxBenen/MaxBenen.github.io)[image: Github Pages]

Comment: Hi Max, I see your site loaded here https://maxbenen.github.io/

Answer (score 0):

First step create the branch with name gh-pages, like this.
[create branch name gh-pages][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/55z6f.png

select that branch, waiting progress and then you can get url pages, like this
[github pages url][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NF5Z5.png

Comment: After waiting for a day, I noticed that the GitHub Pages only load the page header. Does that imply that the entire page will eventually load as well?